# Many-to-Many in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

I need to model a user sharing an item with other users, in Cassandra.

In a relational db, I'd model it with a cross reference table like so:

**USER_SHARE**

- from_user: foreign key
- to_user: foreign key
- item_id: int
- item_type: varchar

I need to query to find:

1) Given a user, what items they have shared, and with whom
2) Given a user, has a given item been shared with a given user
3) Given a user, what items they have shared with them, and by whom
4) Given an item, is it shared with user X

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra you do this with denormalization.
You should create a items_by_users and users_by_items -- in practice you have to model data in order to answer all your queries. Probably you will need a logged batch while inserting data to guarantee the atomicity of writing in all tables

Comment: Jay Patel has an excellent description of this: http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in Cassandra. But you will not be able to enforce the integrity constraints you would imposefif you were using SQL.